# android image fadein or fadeout

Tags: android, image, fadein, fadeout

What is the simplest way to fade-in or fade-out an image in android?

I am reading images from the SD-card one after the other automatically with no button clicking (like a slideshow) so when the new image comes up i want a fade in or fade out effect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use R.anim.fadeout & R.anim.fadein........

try this link [Animation](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343)